# How can I better address this question being flagged as "on-hold/opinion based"?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

[My SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665061/what-do-berkshelf-api-and-chef-supermarket-do-differently-than-traditional-artif)

I have reviewed both my question and answer multiple times and find no opinion in it.

I'm also confused that the question is marked "on-hold/opinion-based" yet there is no note regarding why it was flagged this way.

I'd really appreciate if anyone more experienced than I could help me figure this out.

I'm trying to share the answer to my original question which seems (for one reason or another) to be a confusing and sparsely documented portion of the applications involved.

Comment: For starters, don't add meta information about the post to the post. Lines asking down/close voters to explain themselves don't go in the question.

Comment: Well, if the question wasn't opinion based, it would certainly be too broad.  It's one of the two.

Comment: I would have voted to close this as "too broad". There could be no differences or a million differences, it depends on how granular an answer you're looking for. "They're more or less the same" and "Here are 100 ways in which they differ" are equally valid answers depending on your actual problem.

Comment: @meagar: There is a distinct reason why Berkshelf-API needs to be used to store/resolve cookbooks and why we cannot use other well-known artifact repositories: the .JSON file that it returns. I don't understand why that would be interpreted as 'too broad'.

Comment: While I would admit that there is more detail in the answer than the bare minimum to answer the question, I feel it provides necessary context and information to an area that is widely-misunderstood, leading to the reason I originally asked the question.

Comment: Does not appear to still be on hold...

Comment: Sometimes the wisdom of the crowd doesn't seem terribly wise. That's life on Stack Overflow; you just have to shrug and go on. Besides, being on hold is not necessarily bad. Your question/answer remain and can still be upvoted, reopened, etc (as in fact it has been). And you don't really _need_ the question reopened; it's been answered (by you).

Comment: @matt: true, thanks for the advice. Happy SO'ing